# why does this seem to be an infinite loop?

Tags: python

```
#This (python code) program will find the hcf of a given list of numbers.
A = [10, 15, 25, 35, 90]     #creates and initializes the list of numbers

def greatest_common_devisor(a):
  factor_list = []         #creates a blank list that will be used to store all common factors
  factor = 1               #creates and initializes the number that will be used to check if it
                          #is a factor of the numbers in the list
  counter = 0          #initializes a counter variable to control the while loop

  while counter <= len(a):    #Begining of while loop with number of iterations = length of array
    if a[counter] % factor == 0:  #checking to see if the variable factor is a factor of the number inside list a
      counter += 1           #incrementing counter to move to the next element/number within list a
      if counter == len(a):   #if the variable factor is a factor, and we have reached the end of the array,
                              #that means the variable factor is a factor of all the numbers in list a
        factor_list.append(factor) #if variable factor is a factor of all the numbers in list a
                                    # we then add it to the new array will be used to stor all common factors
    counter = 0 #Setting back counter to 0 so we can go back to the begining of the array
                 #to restart the process of checking the next value of variable factor
    factor += 1  #incrementing to check the next consecutive number

  print factor_list  #when i get this to work i will loop through factor_list and print the biggest number, i.e. the hcf

greatest_common_devisor(A)
```

Comment: `len(a)` never decreases - that's why (put a `print(a)` in your loop to see that)

Comment: `counter = 0` is done at the end of every loop.. `counter` is always 0 and always less than `len(a)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#This program will find the hcf of a given list of numbers.

A = [65, 20, 100, 85, 125]     #creates and initializes the list of numbers

def greatest_common_devisor(_A):
  iterator = 1
  factor = 1
  a_length = len(_A)
  largest = 99999

#get the largest number
for number in _A: #iterate through array
  if number < largest: #if current not the highest number
    largest = number #set to highest

while iterator <= largest: #iterate from 1 ... largest number
for index in range(0, a_length): #loop through array
  if _A[index] % iterator != 0: #if the element is not equally divisible by 0
    break #stop and go to next element
  if index == (a_length - 1): #if we reach the last element of array
    factor = iterator #it means that all of them are divisibe by 0
iterator += 1 #let's increment to check if array divisible by next iterator
#print the factor
print factor

print "The highest common factor of: ",
for element in A:
  print element,
print " is: ",
greatest_common_devisor(A)
```

Comment: This code will be more efficient if you compare the factor agaist the smallest number as opposed to the largest number; therefore, the first for loop can be changed to get the smallest number from the list instead of the largest... Remember that the largest number cannot be a factor of any of the other smaller numbers, but the smallest number can be a factor of all the other numbers.

Comment: just change the variable largest to smallest........it was actually meant to be smallest.....i just forgot to change the variable name.

Answer (score 2):

You set `counter` to `0` every loop, so `if counter == len(a)` and `while counter <= len(a)` are going to evaluate to the same thing every loop, thus making it infinite.

Comment: Is there a way to fix this algorithm so that it works or should I try a different approach?